# IndexRoute in react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Since IndexRoute is no longer supported by react-router, how can I render child components?

I have the following component:

```js
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="centered-wrapper">
          {this.props.children}
        </div>                
        <div className="who">[ <a href="">Who's Marco</a> ]</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I want to be able to render App all the time and inside it, a component depending on the URL. In case of root, I want to render the Welcome component. Something that previously could be achieve with this:

```js
<Router history={browserHistory}>
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={Welcome} />
    <Route path="life" component={Life} />
  </Route>
</Router>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no route nesting in v4. You'll need to define routes in your components instead.

Change your setup above to

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
  <Route path="/" component={App} />
</Router>
```

Then in the `App` component (that is, in its `render` method), define the other routes

```
...
<Route path="life" component={Life} />
<Route
    exact
    path="/"
    component={Welcome}
/>
...
```